# Use default field type(s) within my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes

I am just experimenting with plugin development and would like to use the existing [dateTime field type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/date-time-fields). For no other reason than to maintain consistency throughout my application.

Is there a way to call that field as a macro (for lack of better words) in my template or do I just view the generated source from one spot and copy/paste it into my templates?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the default field types are exposed as template [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) in `/craft/app/templates/_includes/forms.html`. Here's how you could easily create a DateTime input field:

```
{% import '_includes/forms' as forms %}

{{ forms.date( {
    id : 'myDateField',
    name : 'myDateField',
    value : myDate | default
} ) }}
```

Note that for the date field, `value` needs to be a valid DateTime object.

Other input types – such as a plain text field – are created in a similar manner:

```
{{ forms.text( {
    id: 'myTextField',
    name: 'myTextField',
    value : myValue | default,
    placeholder : 'My Placeholder',
} ) }}
```

Also note that as `_includes/forms` is outside the frontend `templates` folder, it will not be easily accessible outside the CP. If you want to include the form macros in a frontend template, see [the following SE thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4844/1098) – I'm partial to Mike Pepper's answer, myself.

Comment: Fantastic! I figured there was a way other than copy/paste html.